# Gridview Column as Row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, charts

On an ASP NET project I have a gridview control with the following information:

```
Column A   Column B   Column C   Graph
Value A    1          9          Graph A
Value B    3          7          Graph B
```

The graph column has a Chart control on each row being that the information o each chart represents the values of eack row, for example, Graph A has a bar chart whith 10% and 90% and Graph B has a bar chart with 30% and 70%.

No what I would like to know is the easiest way to represent information like this:

```
Column A   Column B   Column C
Value A    1          9
         Graph A
Value B    3          7
         Graph B
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) for Column B. Then you can use any HTML you like there. 
For example:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column B"  >
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblColumnB" /><br/>
       <asp:Image ID="ImgChart" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can bind the Data for example in GridView's [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)-Handler.

```
  void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      var data = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
      var LblColumnB = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LblColumnB");
      var ImgChart = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("ImgChart");
      // Bind data or load the controls ....
    }
  }
```